# Where can I find a flexible logging library for Windows Mobile?

Tags: c++, logging, windows-mobile

Can anyone suggest any open and free library for logging on Windows Mobile application written in C++?

It would be nice if it supports logging to files, syslog (would be nice) and logging level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I know of.

You will most likely have to look for source code available logging libraries.  Windows Mobile will pretty much compile most win32 code with no or little changes, so any win32 logging library should work.

Generally I build my own as I like fine gained control over my logging code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could see if the logging from http://pt-framework.sourceforge.net/ fits your needs. I don't know if syslog is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using log4net in one of my compact framework projects.   It's probably not ideal for production though, as the dll is 220k!

Comment: And way less than ideal for the requested C++